# What is the best way to show images saved in Blob store in databases?

Tags: php, file, http, file-upload

Concrete Example: I'm saving my images in MySQL on a Blob colum (let's call it 'image'). I'm using CakePHP (doesn't really matters)

That's is the avatar image of the users. I need to show it to them.

Now, what's the best way of doing that?

currently, i'm using a separate action "show_image/{user_id}" that reads the image from the database, set headers and print the content. So, if i want to display the image i just use:

```
<img src="show_image/3" />
```

show_image is something like:

```
function show_image($user_id){
    $user = //read user from database
    $image = file_get_contents($user['image']);
    header('Content-type: ' . $user['image_type']);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$user['image_name'].'"');
    echo $image;
}
```

Now, maybe there are other ways (base64 maybe) or something that works better than this approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would base64 work better? :) Images are (generally) binary. Let them live as such unless there is a good reason otherwise. However, this *really should* support caching / "Not Modified" as to minimize wasted bandwidth. In general, I prefer to keep "data files" outside the database itself... but there are arguments both ways.

Comment: Thanks brother. Caching!!!! You're right. I was thinking in base64 to transmit it in the src attr of the img tag. Of course it doesn't seem a good idea, but it's another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've done the usual way as the question say.

Just added the header cache thing pointed by @pst.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the image as a binary object, you should probably just upload the file to a location and store the location string in the DB. This will reduce the load on your DB as well as being generally much easier.

Comment: You're right. I've done it several times, but my requirements are different now. Thanks for the answer.